# How to check not equalto in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.One table contain the values
`+---------+`
`Users`
`---------+`
A
B
C
D
E
F
`+----------+`

And in another table I am having
`+--------+`
`Active`
`+--------+`
C
D
G
H
I
`` `+--------+ ``

From the two table I need to get the Users only those who are not in the Active.For this the expected result is 
`+------+`
`Result`
`+------+`
A
B
E
F
`+-------+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from users u 
where not exists (
     select 1 from active a where u.Field  = a.Field
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this (replace id with your fields name):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  users u
WHERE
  id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM active WHERE id = u.id)
```